In UWP App, using DependencyProperty, FontSize and FontStyle of TextBlock are changed but FontFamily is not changed
Using UWP I want to print an report that contains TextBlocks. Depending on the preferences I want to change TextBlock FontSize, FontStyle and FontFamily but DependencyProperty changes FontSize and FontStyle only and FontFamily is not changing. Please help me out.
<Page.DataContext>
<vm:MainViewModel x:Name="mainViewModel" />

</Page.DataContext>
 <Paragraph>

     <InlineUIContainer>

         <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PrintArterialVelocities}"

                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"

                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"

                Margin="0">

             <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                 <DataTemplate>

                     <Grid>

                         <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                             <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

                         </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                             <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>

                             <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>

                             <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>

                             <ColumnDefinition Width="173"/>

                             <ColumnDefinition Width="175"/>

                             <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>

                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                         <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                         <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                         <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" local:VelocitiesText.Text="{Binding ArteryName}"/>

                         <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" local:VelocitiesText.Text="{Binding ArteryVelocity}"/>

                         <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" local:VelocitiesText.Text="{Binding ArteryName}"/>

                         <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" local:VelocitiesText.Text="{Binding ArteryVelocity}"/>

                     </Grid>

                 </DataTemplate>

             </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

         </ItemsControl>

     </InlineUIContainer>

 </Paragraph>

Callback Class
public class VelocitiesText
{
 public static string GetText(DependencyObject obj)

 {

     return (string)obj.GetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty);

 }

 public static void SetText(DependencyObject obj, string value)

 {

     obj.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, value);

 }



 public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =

     DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Text", typeof(string), typeof(VelocitiesText), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, callback));

 public static void callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)

 {

     var Txt = (TextBlock)d;

     var InsertString = (string)e.NewValue;            

     Txt.Text = InsertString;

 // Txt.FontFamily= new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.FontFamily(TextCalls.SelectedFontFamilyName);

     Txt.FontFamily= TextCalls.SelectedFontFamily;

     Txt.FontSize = double.Parse(TextCalls.SelectedFontSize);

     if (TextCalls.SelectedFontStyle == "Italic")

         Txt.FontStyle = Windows.UI.Text.FontStyle.Italic;          

 }

}

I can't reproduce the same behavior, you need to check whether TextCalls.SelectedFontFamily is correct. You can also set a fixed value (like   Txt.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");) to test first.

It is recommended to check whether TextCalls.SelectedFontFamily is correct. You can also set a fixed value (like Txt.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Segoe UI");
